# Cannot evaluating variable within IF and For loop using TCL

Tags: tcl

In following code in TCL I cannot seem evaluate the variable "a"

I'm evaluating x and y, in the same For Loop I have a IF statement that is checking for a range between x and y.

If valid then I'd like to perform some more calculations within the IF condition.

Every thing is fine up to the IF condition, but I cant seem to evaluate "a".

I'm trying to set "a" to the value of "y" for all the values within the range $min <= $x && $x <= $max

I would kindly request the experts to highlight the mistake.

```
for {set i 0} {$i < $lenght} {incr i} {

set x [expr ([lindex $cal1 $i])*$offset]

set y [expr ((cal2)/2) ]


if {$min <= $x && $x <= $max } {

puts "is Active"

set a [lindex $y $i]
puts a = $a

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot that seems problematic in your code.

1. In the first line, you use the variable `lenght`. Tcl doesn't care about spelling, but if you don't have such a variable (you might possibly have a `length` variable instead) you will get an error.
2. In the invocation `expr ([lindex $cal1 $i])*$offset]` you have an unnecessary parenthesis but no braces around the expression (the braces aren't mandatory but should be there unless there is a very good reason to omit them). Also: "offset" usually means something you add to, not multiply with, another value. The invocation `expr {[lindex $cal1 $i] * $offset}]` would be better.
3. The variable `y` is used as a list argument to `lindex` later on, but it's created as a scalar variable. Also, your expression divides a string (or rather, an invalid bareword) with 2. Maybe you meant `lappend y [expr {$cal2 / 2}]`? If you use `lappend`, each value will be added to the end of an existing list, or as the first element of a new list if `y` doesn't exist. This is usually what one wants, but it means that the list `y` should be reset using `set y [list]` or `set y {}` before entering the loop, to get rid of elements added earlier, if any.
4. `puts a = $a` won't work, because if there are more than one argument to `puts` they are expected to be the flag `-nonewline` and/or a channel id to send the output to. Maybe you meant `puts "a = $a"`.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thank you for your feedback. Firstly apologies, I had to copy a snippet from a larger chuck of code. Therefore ended up making a few errors even when copying! I am using offset as you mentioned but also reusing it as a gain.